# Power adapter 12V for charging LiFePo4 12V battery with BMS with passive balancing

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, adapter, bms, cell-balancing

I have a project where I need to charge an Enerpower LIFEPO4 Battery of 12V 12Ah with BMS with an integrated passive balancer, protection against overcharge, deep discharge, over-discharge (temperature monitoring):

https://enerprof.de/en/lifepo4-batteries/lifepo4-battery-packs/lifepo4-battery-packs-12v/469/enerpower-lifepo4-12v-12.8v-12.8ah-163wh?c=25

As I understood it isn't possible to charge it with the 14V 4A power adapter directly, and i would need some charging circuit inbetween.

I cannot use the 220V AC power supply directly (requirement), but have to charge the battery from a 14V DC power source. So i would be looking for a 3 stage charging circuit to buy, but cannot find anything price appropriate. Or maybe there is another solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Basically you just haven't read what voltage the battery needs to be correctly charged.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question. The battery needs 14.4V to charge.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't charge a battery with a power supply, you need a battery charger. A BMS is not a charger either.

Comment: I am not really understanding than, how is a laptop charging its battery. There is a power adapter and in the laptop itself there is a balancer and some kind of charging circuit i assume. This charging circuit is what i would need, but  i dont know how it works or is called and if i could just buy it.

Comment: A laptop or mobile phone gets power from a power supply and the charging circuit to charge the battery is inside the laptop or mobile phone. You need a LiFePo battery charger that has suitable specs to match the specs of the battery to charge it with suitable voltages and currents.

Comment: The problem is that i dont have a 220V AC, but have a 14V DC power supply, from which i need to charge the battery. And i couldn't find price appropriate DC/DC onboard chargers or charging circuits to buy.

Comment: Updated the question with this requirement

Comment: @KatjaF You asked a question if it is possible to charge a battery with just a power supply and that question was answered. Now you removed the original question which invalidates an answer, and the edited question is basically asking what to buy, which is off-topic. You also said you found items which don't have an appropriare price, but fail to mention what price point you are aiming. If you have a new question, ask a new question, don't edit away a question you received an answer.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I will post another question.